# How to make RDS::DbInstance accessible from EC2::Instance?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I'm currently using Cloud Formation to deploy a stack where I deploy, among other things:

- A VPC
- A Subnet inside the created VPC
- An EC2 Instance inside the created Subnet
- A RDS Postgres database

At first I couldn't connect to the DBInstance because it didn't have a properly configured SecurityGroup.

When I tried to create the SecurityGroup, the deploy failed because the DBInstance and the SecurityGroup were being created on different VPCs.

But I can't find a property on any RDS related resource on Cloud Formation to adjust in which VPC is my database going to be created. Searching around, I've found the alternative of creating a DBSubnetGroup.

But in order to use a DBSubnetGroup, I need to have at least two subnets (because it needs to cover at least 2 Availability Zones). I wish to avoid creating an empty subnet on another AZ just to make this work.

Is there a better alternative? What's the easiest way to give my EC2 instances access to my DBInstance using only Cloud Formation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go with the *DBSubnetGroup* way, the only possibility of creating RDS instance is to use Default VPC. If you do not specify DBSubnetGroup, your RDS Instance will be created in the default VPC.

Now there are two ways for your EC2 instance to access the RDS Instance.

1. Let your RDS Instance be publicly accessible. Ensure that you have tight SecurityGroup configurations to deny possibility of attacks. Then EC2 instance should be able to access the database instance.
2. Mark publicly accessible as `false`. Connect the Default VPC with the VPC which you have created using VPC Peering Connections. I recommend this way as your RDS instance will not be publicly accessible and you get your job done.

On top of this, you have mentioned

> But in order to use a DBSubnetGroup, I need to have at least two subnets (because it needs to cover at least 2 Availability Zones). I wish to avoid creating an empty subnet on another AZ just to make this work.

RDS doesn't work that way. When you specify `MultiAZ = true` and have `DBSubnetGroup`,  in your RDS template, a replica for your DBInstance will be maintained in another subnet that is available in different AZ. When your primary node goes down, this replica node comes up and acts as the master. Keeping this in mind, I would strongly recommend you to use DBSubnetGroup when creating RDS instance.

More reading available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Subnets)

Hope this helps.